# Nav menu won't open or close on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I've been trying to make this hamburger Menu Work for the longest time now and I've tried a lot, but I just keep going in circles for some reason the menu won't open( Menu not opening is the PROBLEM :(  ),

I got the menu from learning how to create it from this tutorial -> [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDh7Mdl2oww)

Please let me know how I could fix this or refer me to similar post, Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
  });

});
```

```css
header nav ul {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #6134A3;
}

header nav ul.open {
  height: auto;
}

.burger-nav {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(images/nav.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 10%;
  background-position: 97%;
  background-color: #502196;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>MENU</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.css" />
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>

</style>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav>
        <a class="burger-nav"></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--watch this video to finish drop down https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDh7Mdl2oww -->


  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" scr="menu.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the Browser Console? Are you getting any error?

Comment: You are getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in your snippet

Comment: surprisingly I'm not getting any errors, and thank you for the fast response. @VolcovMeter

Comment: I was getting ("Uncaught ReferenceError") that but not anymore but i am on jsfiddle @WojtekT

Comment: Seems like your code is working now.

Comment: its working here but not on my browser I've even tried clearing my cache @VolcovMeter

Comment: I mean - side note - why do you have two script sources for jQuery? You only need one.

Comment: I'm only using one src that's under the head of my html someone added to this question the second src which is over the the head. side note i'm a noob to jquery. @VolcovMeter

Comment: i created a new files and put the css, html, and jquery all in one file and it worked! so something is causing it to not open and close, its weird but ill start working with the file that works, Thanks for the help! @VolcovMeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use latest version of jquery....

```
<head>
  <title>MENU</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, I was able to fix my problem by creating a new file and putting all the css and jquery into my html.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of height: auto property. You should set certain value. like 400px, or 100vh. Or you can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
          $("header nav ul").slideToggle(400);
    });
});

header nav ul {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  background: #6134A3;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately your answer didn't work, :( . I don't understand why it not working its so weird, Thank You for the answer i appreciate it!